# Placing A Thousand Lines Of 24 Integers In A Listview

Tags: c#, listview

I have placed a `ListView` on my main form.

I put 24 columns in it

I set the `view` to `details`

I have an array of integers like this

```
    public static int[] myArrayOfIntegers = new int[24];
    public static bool TheArrayIsNowReady = false;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    string UserSeesThis;
```

Now for my request for help, please. There are 151 properties and 233 Methods associated with a ListView. Could someone please help me to understand how to place my 24 integers in this listview for the user to see them ?

```
        if (TheArrayIsNowReady)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 24; i++)
            {
                UserSeesThis = myArrayOfIntegers[i].ToString();
                listView1._____what___do___I___put___here___[i] = UserSeesThis;
            }
        }
```

After doing one line, I'm going to have to put 500 more lines in the list box, and let the user scroll back through them. (We're hunting bogus numbers, if it matters)

In my dream app, I'll let the user scroll back five or six thousand lines.

The user is going to run a test, and an external box will send the PC 500 sets of 24 numbers. I want to put those on the screen for the user to see. I would like to be able to handle the same five and ten times over.

Comment: I don't understand. You're overwriting the value of `UserSeesThis` in each iteration. What is your expected result? also, please clarify. Is this winforms?? There are multiple UI technologies in .Net, not just the one you're using, so there are many different `ListView` classes in the whole .Net library.

Comment: Check. WinForms. Will update original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a listviewitem, `ListViewItem item = new ListviewItem("firstvalue");`

2) Create subitems for each column, `item.SubItems.add("value");`

3) Add item to list, `listView1.Items.Add(item);`

```
    public static int[] myArrayOfIntegers = new int[24];
    public static bool TheArrayIsNowReady = false;
    int i, j, k;
    string UserSeesThis = "?";
    ListViewItem item;


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TheArrayIsNowReady = true;
        if (TheArrayIsNowReady)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 24; i++)
            {
                myArrayOfIntegers[i] = i;
                if (i == 0) { item = new ListViewItem(myArrayOfIntegers[0].ToString()); }
                item.SubItems.Add(myArrayOfIntegers[i].ToString());
                UserSeesThis = "?";
            }
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you. a lot. Another method will fill `myArrayOfIntegers` for me, so I'm going to assume that your line `myArrayOfIntegers[i] = i;` can be removed from my implementation here.

Comment: Yes it can, I just added it for testing purposes, same with the array is ready, you should choose where to put it. or in what case

Comment: I'm getting  the 0th element showing up twice, and the 23rd element not appearing. I tried taking the `if (i==0)` stuff to a line before the `for (i=0; i<24; i++)` loop and I get the same thing

Comment: Remove the line with if (i==0), I used it to create an initial item, and then you add the subitems

Comment: Now I'm just getting the 0th element and the 23rd element, and no other columns

Comment: Well you said in original post that you already added columns, are they still in the property? you should be able to see them: listview -> properties -> columns, if not you can either add them by code or by adding them there

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23790/discussion-between-user-1-and-csharp-student)